# Attribute DisplayName in C# applied in Spring boot (thymeleaf)

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

in C#, there is attribute [DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-displayname) and you can print in Razor template.

Is there such a way to apply in [spring boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) using [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)?

```
[DisplayName("User Name")]
private string username;
```

in Razor (C#)
@DisplayFor(l => l.username), output => Username

Thanks.

Comment: wrong tag used - you would be better off asking those over in `spring boot` or `thymeleaf` groups

Comment: thanks, i tried springboot, but not enough reputation., now, put spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

From spring-boot controller you can add

```
 @GetMapping("/greeting")
   public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", name);
      return "greeting";
   }
```

Your attribute, and if you want to use it in thymeleaf template you need to use like this:

```
 <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
```

For more information : https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: thanks for reply. that's not what i want. it should be done having annotation.

Comment: Why isn't this what you want? What exactly are you expecting?